# The specified bucket does not exist AWS CLI locally

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have this piece of code in java, using  the aws library:

```
        AmazonS3URI uri = new AmazonS3URI("s3://test");

        String sourceKey = "test.xml";
        String sourceBucket = uri.getBucket();
        String destKey = fileName;

        if(s3Client.doesBucketExistV2(destBucketName)) {
            log.info("enters");
        }

        if(s3Client.doesBucketExistV2(uri.getBucket()) && s3Client.doesBucketExistV2(destBucketName)) {
            log.info("Source bucket: " + uri.getBucket() + " Destiny bucket: " + destBucketName);
            CopyObjectRequest copyObjRequest = new CopyObjectRequest(sourceBucket, sourceKey, destBucketName, destKey);
            s3Client.copyObject(copyObjRequest);
        } else {
            log.info("Bucket does not exist: " + uri.getBucket());
        }

    }
```

When I run this code, on the copyObject command, it is returned that the bucket does not exists (The specified bucket does not exist (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchBucket; Request ID: null; S3 Extended Request ID: null)), but it does, because I'm literally making a condition there. What can the problem be?

Comment: where are you running this from? if locally executed, check your AWS creds have enough permissions to access the bucket. If other services like EC2 or Lambda, check the respective roles have permissions to S3 buckets

Comment: It is running locally. Is there any way to set permissions locally?

Comment: you need to reach out to your AWS account administrator to add permissions to the user/role you are using locally

Comment: In your code you are not initialising `destBucketName`. May be the snippet here is missing it. In any case, a 404 being returned means that the bucket doesn't exist. If it was a permission issue a 403 would have been returned. Can you figure out if it is the `sourceBucket` or `destBucketName` that is throwing the error? Also if `destBucketName` is not created by you, log the it's value to confirm that any prefix is not there in that.

Comment: the source and the destBucket name are the same. I tried hardcoding them, and the same problem happens.